# Overriding or disabling ${python:Depends} at stdeb bdist_deb invocation

Tags: python, debian, packaging, setup.py, debhelper

I am trying to package my Python software with [stdeb](https://github.com/astraw/stdeb):

```
python setup.py --command-packages=stdeb.command bdist_deb
```

which works fine.

Unfortunately, stdeb adds the variable `${python:Depends}` to the **debian/control** file. This placeholder is automatically processed by `dh_python2` from `debhelper` and gets replaced by a string containing multiple Python versions, e.g.: `"python2.7, python (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2), python (<< 2.8)"`.

**How can I get rid of these automatically added Python versions or how can I override `${python:Depends}`?**

Note: The actual problem is the `python` dependency. The target system provides the package `python2.7` with version `2.7.3`, but `python` is still at `2.6.6`.

Comment: FYI, it looks like this is the same issue as https://github.com/astraw/stdeb/issues/49.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually need to do instead is to add something like `X-Python-Version: >= 2.6` to source package in `debian/control` and to add `python-all` or `python-all-dev` to `Build-Depends`. This will work if you're building for the right suite where `python-all` depends on both `python2.6` and `python2.7`. It is a good idea to use `pbuilder` in order to build for target system especially if it is different from your development environment.
Please do not override `${python:Depends}` -- it is wrong and will do no good.

Comment: I ended up hacking the file `util.py` right within stdeb's source code. I replaced `${misc:Depends}` and `${python:Depends}` with the desired Python dependency I need.

But you're correct: The best way would be to use `pbuilder`.

Comment: What you're doing is shocking. Just replace `${python:Depends}` in `debian/control` with `${my:Depends}` and add `override_dh_gencontrol` to `debian/rules` as follows: `dh_gencontrol -- -Vmy:Depends="pkg1, pkg2"`

Comment: Can you give more details about using pbuilder?

Comment: See http://pbuilder.alioth.debian.org,  

[pbuilder\(8\)](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pbuilder&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en),  

https://wiki.debian.org/PbuilderTricks

Answer (score 0):

You can force the *stdeb* python dependencies through `XS-Python-Version` option. For instance, by creating  `stdeb.cfg`  file with:

```
[DEFAULT]
XS-Python-Version: 2.6
```

Other means to set this options may be setupg.cfg in `[sdist_dsc]` section, or in command line (`sdist_desc  --xs-python-version 2.6 bdist_deb`) but it did not actually work for me.